# php shuffle with conditions

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have a large JSON file with more than 200 items. There are 5 groups data in it. each group has at least 30 items. I distinguish them using `"p" tag`, like `"p":"1","p":"2","p":"3","p":"4","p":"5"` in the json data. Now I want get 2 items from each group and total for 10 items with a random orders.

For an easy explanation, I set some simple data like below. "p":"1" have 4 items in its group, "p":"2" have 4 items in its group.

Now how to make get 2 items from `"p":"1"` and 2 items with `"p":"2"` with a random orders?

```
$json = <<<ETO
[
   {
      "a":"apple",
      "p":"1"
   },
   {
      "a":"orange",
      "p":"1"
   },
   {
      "a":"pear",
      "p":"1"
   },
   {
      "a":"banana",
      "p":"1"
   },
   {
      "a":"Chauli",
      "p":"2"
   },
   {
      "a":"Carrot",
      "p":"2"
   },
   {
      "a":"Lettuce",
      "p":"2"
   },
   {
      "a":"Potato",
      "p":"2"
   }
]
ETO;

$data = json_decode($json);
shuffle($data);// some shuffle like this is very ugly...
foreach($data as $row){                         
      $aoo = 1;
      $boo = 1;
      if($row->p==1){
          echo $row->p.': '.$row->a.'<br />';
          $aoo++;
          if($aoo==2){
            break;  
          }
      }
      if($row->p==2){
          echo $row->p.': '.$row->b.'<br />';
          $boo++;
          if($boo==2){
            break;  
          }
      }
}
```

I need get the result like:

`orange ("p":"1") Carrot ("p":"2") pear ("p":"1") Lettuce ("p":"2")`

`Lettuce ("p":"2") banana ("p":"1") Apple ("p":"1") Chauli ("p":"2")`

In one word, get 2 Vegetables and 2 Fruits combine for a mixed orders. Thanks.

Comment: Separate the items into individual groups. Get two random items from each group, put them all into one array. Shuffle the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$values = json_decode($json, true);

$grouped = array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $grouped[$value['p']][] = $value;
}

$chosen = array();
foreach ($grouped as $group) {
    $keys = array_rand($group, 2);
    $chosen = array_merge($chosen, array_intersect_key($group, array_flip($keys)));
}

shuffle($chosen);
```

Comment: Any reason not to just say `foreach (array_rand($group, 2) as $key) { $chosen[] = $group[$key]; }`?

Comment: @cHao Ewh, two nested loops... ;-P

Comment: You have them anyway; they're just hidden inside all that array magic.  :)  Which, by the way, is considerably harder to follow than a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: This answer would be improved by including an educational explanation.

Answer (score 3):

- Re-arrange the data so your array looks like

  1=>array(apple, orange, pear, ...),
  2=>array(Chauli, Carrot, Potato),
  3=>...
- pick 2 elements from each array via array_rand
- append those two elements to one output array
- shuffle that temporary array